# RabbitMQ - Basic newbie questions

Tags: rabbitmq

Our scenario: dozens of Windows laptops which are occasionally connected to the network. Need to store simple data records on each laptop, then have these reliably transferred to a service running on the network once connection is available. Considering RabbitMQ on each laptop, feeding data to a "main" RabbitMQ on the network. This is a Fortune 100, and packaging etc is a concern.

Question 1: In general, does Rabbit make sense here? If not, any suggestions for an approach?

Question 2: When I installed on Win I had to manually install Erlang first. Are there packaging/deployment options which are simpler/more friendly? (Their IT people can do all the normal deployment stuff including create win service, but installing Erlang on user machines might raise eyebrows...)

Thanks for any help from those of you who've been there, done that with Rabbit.

Answer (score 5):

Question 1: What you need is a store and forward mechanism. RabbitMQ can be used for that, actually by using the [Shovel](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2010/02/01/rabbitmq-shovel-message-relocation-equipment) plug-in to take care of moving messages from the local Rabbit to the remote one (handling reconnection, retries, etc... for you).

Question 2: The answer is related to question 1. RabbitMQ+Shovel is conceptually suitable for your store and forward needs but if, alas, not technologically acceptable, you may want to consider simpler/cruder approaches like... SMTP!

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows laptops are backed by a windows infrastructure, the most logical choice is MSMQ, which offers this "Out-of-the-box"; e.g. store and forward from clients to server(s). Easy to install by policy and administrate.